# Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size, clarification needed

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

As you can see from the below snippet arrays are of the same size

```
=SUMIFS(
           $J$12:$J$38,
   ">=0",  $K$12:$K$38,
   "="&Y47,$M$12:$M$38
)
```

Yet, I am getting an error `Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size.`

Please help me understand what is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum range is the first parameter of the function, not the last. Please try

```
=SUMIFS($M$12:$M$38, $J$12:$J$38, ">=0",  $K$12:$K$38, "="&Y47)
```

and see if that works?

REFERENCE:

- [SUMIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

Comment: indeed it does. Thank you very much for taking the time and helping out. I'll accept answer in ~3 min